# How can I get messages from a Telegram channel with the Telegram API

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram-bot

How can I access to a Telegram channel messages with a bot registered as channel admin?

I am trying to get all the messages from Telegram channel and display them in an ASP.NET webpage (c#)

I am able to get updates when new message sent directly to the bot:

```
var json = wc.DownloadString(" https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getUpdates");
```

but its not working for the channel.

Comment: do you know how to get messages from telegram bot that were sent by other people using `/start` command? Thanks.

Comment: The new @ifttt telegram bot can help.

Comment: What you called `Telegram API` really is `Telegram Bot API`.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately it's not possible yet.(they may come up with something in future) as admin you can just send messages to channel.

Comment: sorry. not yet.

Comment: No, you can receive from channels in updates, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327592/12852914)

Answer (score 1):

You can receive channel posts and channel post editing.

But you won't receive it in `OnMessage` event, you can receive it from `OnUpdate` as `Message` object like code below:

**Note:** The bot must be an administrator in the channel.

```cs
private static readonly TelegramBotClient Bot = new TelegramBotClient("my-real-token");

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Bot.StartReceive(UpdateType.ChannelPost, UpdateType.EditedChannelPost);
    Bot.OnUpdate += Bot_OnUpdate;
}
    
public static void OnUpdate(UpdateEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Update.Type == UpdateType.ChannelPost)
    {
        Message post = e.Update.ChannelPost;
        //TODO: Store channel post
    }
    else if (e.Update.Type == UpdateType.EditedChannelPost)
    {
        Message editedPost = e.Update.EditedChannelPost;
        //TODO: Store edited channel post
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way until now is as follows:

1. Your bot be added to the channel by its administrator.
2. You set the bot's `privacy` to `disabled`.

Step 1 helps your bot to join the channel so it see the messages.

Step 2 makes your bot listening to all messages of the channel.