# Forward Messages from Telegram to Discord via webhook

Tags: python, discord, telegram-bot

I hope someone here can assist me with an issue I'm encountering in my Telegram bot project. I'm working on a bot that should forward messages sent in a Telegram channel, where the bot has been added, to a Discord server via webhook.

I've properly configured the bot on Telegram and successfully obtained the webhook on Discord. However, I'm unable to get messages sent in the Telegram channel to be forwarded correctly to the Discord server via the webhook. Strangely, the bot is able to fetch messages from private chats with the bot, but not from the channel.

I've carefully reviewed the documentation for both platforms and followed all necessary steps, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone with experience in this area could lend me a hand or suggest where I might have made errors. Any help or advice would be extremely valuable.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

```
import os
import logging
import requests
from telegram import Update, Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CallbackContext, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Set up Telegram bot and Discord webhook
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = ''
DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL = ''

# Create Telegram bot updater and dispatcher
updater = Updater(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Define function to send messages to Discord webhook
def send_to_discord(message):
    # Prepare the data to send
    data = {
        "content": message
    }

    # Send the POST request
    response = requests.post(DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL, json=data)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 204:
        logger.info("Message sent to Discord successfully")
    else:
        logger.error(f"Failed to send message to Discord: {response.status_code} {response.reason}")

# Define function to handle messages and forward them to Discord
def handle_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.message
    if message is not None:
        message_text = message.text
        logger.info(f"Received message from Telegram: {message_text}")

        # Forward the message to Discord
        send_to_discord(message_text)
    else:
        logger.warning("Received an update without a message")

# Add a message handler to the dispatcher
message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), handle_message)
dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler)

# Define function to forward existing messages in the channel
def forward_existing_messages():
    # Create a Telegram bot instance
    bot = Bot(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)

    # Retrieve the last update ID
    updates = bot.get_updates()
    last_update_id = updates[-1].update_id if updates else 0

    # Retrieve the messages in the channel with an offset
    updates = bot.get_updates(offset=last_update_id + 1)

    # Loop through the messages and forward them to Discord
    for update in updates:
        message = update.message
        message_text = message.text
        logger.info(f"Forwarding existing message from Telegram: {message_text}")

        # Forward the message to Discord
        send_to_discord(message_text)

# Forward existing messages in the channel
forward_existing_messages()

# Start the bot
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: You need to be more clear on the specific problem. If I had to guess your first problem is with getting messages from a telegram channel. You phrased your problem as the entire functionality of your project. You also didn't show any code for the discord bot but discord is tagged. You also are taking the difficult path by making a webhook, you can just make a `discord.Embed`. Please check out this post for listening to a telegram channel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526029/how-can-i-get-messages-from-a-telegram-channel-with-the-telegram-api?rq=2